# How to display custom message in jpgraph, when error occures?

Tags: php, error-handling, jpgraph

Sometimes jpgraph can not create graph, in a case of NULL values.

How can I display some custom error message in that case? Like "No results found" or something like that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($instanceofjpgraph === null){
   echo "some error";
}
```